# How to set Powershell ExecutionPolicy via Puppet exec command with unless property on Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, exec, puppet

I am using Puppet Enterprise version 3.8.6 to manage Windows servers.
I am trying to make the setting of the Powershell Execution Policy idempodent. I tested several hypothesis, the last one is this:

```
# Setting Powershell Execution Policy to unrestricted
 exec { 'Set PowerShell execution policy unrestricted':
   command   => 'Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted',
   unless    => 'if ((Get-ExecutionPolicy).ToString().Equals("Unrestricted")) { exit 0 } else { exit 1 }',
   provider  => powershell
 }
```

I already tested with double quotes and signle quotes, even escaping double quotes on Unrestricted word (e.g. \"Unrestricted\").
I also tested the command, but without success:

```
(Get-ExecutionPolicy).ToString(). -eq "Unrestricted"
```

It changes the ExecutionPolicy to Unrestricted, but in every Puppet run. It keeps falling in the else clause. The command works on Powershell.
I would like it to be applied only when it's needed.

FYI: I already checked the Puppet documentation and searched onlne.
some links I checked:
http://glennsarti.github.io/blog/powershell-puppet-module-exit-codes/
https://docs.puppet.com/pe/latest/windows_config_mgmnt.html#executing-arbitrary-powershell-code

Comment: first of all ``(Get-ExecutionPolicy) -eq "Unrestricted"`` is enough, no need for ``tostring()``. And have you considered GPO? DSC? Registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is due to how the PowerShell module calls PowerShell - it passes [`-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` as part of the powershell.exe startup arguments](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-powershell/blob/19dcb796602a79a3e7731b90ad7375305893e3d9/lib/puppet/provider/exec/powershell.rb#L47), so local scope will always return Bypass, thus causing it to fail on the unless every time.

Try adding `-Scope LocalMachine` to your unless statement.

```
# Setting Powershell Execution Policy to unrestricted
 exec { 'Set PowerShell execution policy unrestricted':
   command   => 'Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted',
   unless    => 'if ((Get-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine).ToString() -eq "Unrestricted") { exit 0 } else { exit 1 }',
   provider  => powershell
 }
```