# Puppet shows success when invoking incorrect command using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, puppet, powershell-5.0

I am trying to invoke a PowerShell command from Puppet. The issue is even if the PowerShell command is incorrectly supplied (in this case, `iisres` instead of `iisreset`), Puppet shows *successful* run as shown below:

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Common::Iis::Iis_reset/Utils::Powershell_test[Restart IIS service]/Exec[Running command invoke-command -scriptblock {iisres} -verbose on agent]/returns: executed successfully
```

Few days ago, i had asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484043/capturing-output-error-when-invoking-powershell-script) and the suggestion made in that post was working fine till i came across this issue. Here's the script:

```
[root@pe-server] cat iis_reset.pp
class common::iis::iis_reset {
    utils::powershell_test { 'Restart IIS service':
        command => 'invoke-command -scriptblock {iisres} -verbose',
    }
}


[root@pe-server] powershell_test.pp
define utils::powershell_test (String $command) {
    $powershell = 'C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -NoProfile -NoLogo -NonInteractive'

    exec { "Running command $command on agent":
        command => "$powershell -Command \"& {$command; exit (1 - [int]$?)}\"",
        logoutput => 'on_failure',
    }
}
```

How to fix such issues for good?

Note: I was actually using the Powershell provider by Puppet earlier for all `exec` commands until i faced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484043/capturing-output-error-when-invoking-powershell-script) issue.

Comment: try/catch and exit code approach should help you out I believe. I am not sure if that is exactly what you are looking for or not

Comment: I'm open to suggestions but i would try to avoid try/catch unless there's no other option left.

Comment: Could you please tell the reason for the same? Is there any context on the above point? because catching the exceptions is the best way I felt in your case.

Comment: There are many ways to approach a given problem. I'm not averse to using what you're suggesting but who knows, may be just a tweak in my syntax might help me fix the issue, for good.

Comment: I don't know anything about Puppet but why are you potentially returning a negative exit code? Also I think your issue is that Invoke-Command is running properly so the last command result is ok. Looking to see how you properly pass that to the calling computer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210942/catching-return-code-of-a-command-with-invoke-command-powershell-2 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549184/how-to-capture-the-return-value-of-a-scriptblock-invoked-with-powershells-invok

Comment: @Matt: I'm using `exit (1 - [int]$?)` from the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484043/capturing-output-error-when-invoking-powershell-script) i posted above in my question. Based on the [explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484043/capturing-output-error-when-invoking-powershell-script#comment72194445_42485152), i understood that if the command will fail, it will return FALSE, which when casted to integer will return 0, and thus, to get the right exit code, we will be subtracting it from 1. Please correct me if i misunderstood that explanation.

Comment: @Technext the explanation is correct. Just never done that before so it struck me as odd at first.

Comment: @Matt: BTW, i tried using just `exit ([int]$?)` and there's an interesting observation: Puppet _correctly_ _mentions_ about the non-existent command `iisres`. However, if i use the correct command i.e., `iisreset`, it fails and that it seems is because it worked properly and returned TRUE, which when got converted to integer and exited with failure.